# text editor with custom zoom feature

Tags: windows, text-editor

I am currently using Notepad++. Unfortunately it doesn't have a feature to set custom zoom. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/925000/notepad-set-custom-zoom) is why I need this feature.

Is there any other free text editor that supports this feature?

Comment: Doesn't "Ctrl + Middle mouse button scroll" works on resizing the text on Windows? Working well in Kate on Linux.

Comment: “Zoom” for text doesn't make sense: text doesn't have a size to begin with. If you want a different size, change the font size!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well try the [Atom](http://atom.io) editor that is built on HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

> Is there any other free text editor that supports this feature?

As for being free, it's MIT licensed.

You can set font size not only in pixels but also in all the formats css allows, through customizing the personal style sheet.

Here's a screen shot of the stylesheet editor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try **CudaText** editor. It is free/ open source.

To allow zooming by Ctrl+ mouse wheel, you need to open "Options/ Settings-user" and add option to this file:

```
//Allow to zoom text using Ctrl+mouse wheel
"mouse_wheel_zoom": true,
```

This feature is not handy by default, so option is needed.
Zoom 300%:

[image]